# Can I open more than 2048 sockets using Asio(non-boost) on windows?

Tags: c++, networking, asio

I'm trying to test my server program actually, so I developed a simple program using Asio(non-boost) to simuluate a large number of connections. I ran it on Win7.
However, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/kdfaxaay.aspx
, *The C run-time libraries have a 512 limit for the number of files that can be open at any one time. Attempting to open more than the maximum number of file descriptors or file streams causes program failure. Use _setmaxstdio to change this number.* And `_setmaxstdio` got an error when given a parameter more than **2048**.
Does it mean I cannot open more than 2048 socket on windows using Asio? As a matter of fact, I tried connecting more than 2048 socket, say 4000, to the server, using `async_connect`. And I got them all connected successfully with error_code = 0. I didn't get any program failure. So anyone knows what's going on here? Did I really open 4000 socket on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clue is here:

> The C run-time libraries have a 512 limit for the number of files that can be open at any one time.

The C Run-time Library (CRT) is the library implements the C standard functions for files - `fopen` and so on. It doesn't handle sockets since those aren't part of standard c.

For sockets you use Windows Sockets (Winsock) which is a different library. This limit doesn't apply to it.